# Configuring NTP on IOT-Devkit

Tags: iot-devkit

I'm working in an organization that blocks outbound NTP connections for security reasons.  We have a local NTP server, but for all my searching I've been unable to find a way to configure the IOT-Devkit to connect to it.  I understand why it's desirable to sync time with the IOTHub, but it's simply not an option for us.

Is there a way to configure the device to use a local NTP server?

Answer (score 0):

We have solved this issue internally by making alterations to our DNS to resolve to our local NTP server.

Comment: You could also modify C:\Users\{name}\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\AZ3166\hardware\stm32f4\1.6.0\cores\arduino\systemSystemTime.cpp to add your local NTP server.